# Replacement for WorkItemFormControl with TFS 2015

Tags: wpf, tfs, controls, tfs-workitem, tfs-2015

Quite some time ago, I implemented a tool for creating and maintaining Work Breakdown Structures in combination with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (you can find it here: http://wbseditor.codeplex.com). It was originally implemented using the TFS 2005 object model, and also relies on the `WorkItemFormControl` to display Work Items for creation and editing directly from the application. It's quite useful, and is heavily used inside my company for multi-project management.

A while ago, I ported it to using the TFS 2010 assemblies, but now, a couple of years later, I have the need to also support Visual Studio 2015.

In the course of migrating to the new assemblies, I have managed to get all the `nuget` packages I need (which is `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`), but apparently both the `WorkItemFormControl` (which was targeted for Windows Forms) and the newer WPF equivalent `WorkItemControl` (from the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemControl.WpfControls` namespace) are missing.

I *suppose* I can use a web browser control to achieve a similar effect like before, but I have not found any sample code or similar for this. Does anybody have a pointer how to get a similar effect like I got with `WorkItemFormControl`? I admit I haven't spent more than a couple of hours on research, simply because I just wanted to do a "quick update" to support the new server versions, and this sort of caught me cold.

Is there a "quick fix" for me I just have been to blind to see?

If there is no such thing as a quick fix, which is the general direction I should head to get the functionality back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WorkItemFormControl Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.controls.workitemformcontrol(v=vs.120).aspx) is now obsolete, use the WPF version of this control, `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WorkItemControl` instead.

To use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WorkItemControl` namespace, you need to add assembly `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls` which can be added from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.All` in nuget package.

Comment: OK, the point is apparently that the Controls no longer exist in the >= 14.x versions of the TFS assemblies (which are the ones I tried with first, using `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`). The 12.x versions support most current versions (including 2015), so it is advisable to use those. The nuget package above (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.All`) is a TFS 2013 package (v12).